# Maximum And Minimum With Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to run this but it keeps give me zero value. What is wrong in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int i,min,max,arr[3]={10,20,40};
    int *ptr_arr;
    ptr_arr=&arr[3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      if(max>*ptr_arr)
        max=*ptr_arr;
      if(min>*ptr_arr)
        min=*ptr_arr;
    }

    printf("The Maximum Number Is %d\n ",max);
    printf("The Minimum Number Is %d ",min);
}
```

Comment: this line: `ptr_arr=&arr[3];` is accessing an address beyond the end of the array.  This results in undefined behaviour and could lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the `for` loop is not traversing the array so what ever uninitialized/trash values are at arr[3], min and max on the stack are just compared 3 times.  Suggest: eliminate ptr_arr, initialize max to MIN_INT, initialize min to INT_MAX,  use arr[i[ for the comparison value

Comment: there are only 2 valid declarations of main() (and one optional).  The valid declarations are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  The optional declaration is `int main()` which is the same as `int main( void )`  Note that `char *argv[]` is the same as `char **argv`  When compiling, always enable all warnings, then your compiler would have  told you about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code misses to initialise `min` and `max` to meaningful values.

   Do

   ```
   int min = INT_MAX;
   int max = -INT_MAX;
   ```

   to have the macro above available `#include` `<limits.h>`.
2. `ptr_arr` gets initialised wrongly to point beyond the array.

   Do

   ```
   int * ptr_arr = arr; /* Here the array "decays" to address of its 1st element. */
   ```

   or

   ```
   int * ptr_arr = &arr[0]; /* Explicitly use the address of the array 1st element. */
   ```
3. The code misses to increase `ptr_arr` to successively access all array's element while looping.

   Add

   ```
   ++ptr_arr;
   ```

   as last statement to the loop.

---

Also read your code closely to find a nasty typo in comparing.

---

`main()` should at least read `int main(void)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot man. I did what you said but it gave me this error."error: 'INT_MAX' was not declared in this scope
   int min=INT_MAX;"  and why we give min and max INT_MAX ?

Comment: @alk  You might want to check conditions once .

Comment: @ameyCU: I leave this very bit to the OP.

Comment: @alk Very well Sir !! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ptr_arr=&arr[3];  // points to index which is beyond no. of index of array
```

As declaration of `arr` is `arr[3]={10,20,40};`so it's valid indexes are `0,1 and 2` .So there is no index `3`(array indexing starts with `0`).

Also `min` and `max` what value does they have ? Uninitialized , so how can your code give correct output.

Make the following changes -

```
     int min=arr[0],max=0;
     ...
     ptr_arr=arr;   // points to address of array's first element
```

And in for loop see condition and increment pointer-

```
     if(max>*ptr_arr)  // change condition to max<=*ptr_arr
     ...
     ptr_arr++;
```

See worning example here-https://ideone.com/r3nv8R

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed it, and now it give me the same number. It give me the minimum number which is 10 for max and min. Do you know why?

Comment: @Moayad  See my answer I  told to change the `if` condition.

Comment: Thank you. I have just some questions. First why did you use #include <limits.h>? and can i put ptr_arr++ at the third statment in the array ?

Comment: @Moayad   [`limits.h`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) header which contains marco's like `INT_MAX` as told by alk Sir. What you mean by this `can i put ptr_arr++ at the third statment in the array ? `  is unclear to me .

Comment: i mean in the increment in loop for example can i write for(i=0;i<=3;ptr_arr++) instead of write under the if ? and i have another question why you declare min=a[0]; like this why you didn't declare it like this min=0; and sorry for too many questions i'm new in programming

Comment: @Moayad  Yes but you also need to increment `i`. You can write like this - `for(i=0;i<=3;i++,ptr_arr++) `

Comment: can you please see my question i pressed enter accidentally can you see it again.

Comment: @Moayad   `ptr_arr++` in not inside `if's` it is inside `loop` but outside `if's` . And I wrote `min=a[0]` not `0` because what if there is no `0` in your array like in current case . Then what your program will print `min` as always `0` instead of printing min value from array. **You should try this and explore the WHY .**

Comment: actually i tried it but i still didn't know why you wrote. by the way thanks a lot that was helpful.

Comment: @Moayad  It depends how you want to initialize `min` and `max` .Many ways as also done by alk Sir . Well glad your problem is solved . Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Just few notes on your code:

you should give `min` and `max` an initial value(a value from the array), why? because the initial garbage value might be beyond your array values(say 9999 for example) which yields a wrong result, because your array doesn't have such a value.

Also, im not sure why you need `ptr_arr` ?

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,min,max,arr[3]={10,20,40};
    max = arr[0]; //initialize 'max' to be the first element of the array
    min = arr[0]; //initialize 'min' to be the first element of the array
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      if(arr[i] >= max)
        max = arr[i];
      if(arr[i] <= min)
        min = arr[i];
    }

    printf("The Maximum Number Is %d\n ",max);
    printf("The Minimum Number Is %d ",min);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice also in the `if` statement i added `<=` and `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0,min ,max,arr[3]={20,40,10};

  int *ptr_arr;
  ptr_arr=&arr[0];
  min = max = arr[0];

  for(i=0;i<3;i++){

   if(max < ptr_arr[i]) {
     max=ptr_arr[i];
   }
  
   if(min>ptr_arr[i]){
     min=ptr_arr[i];
   }
 }

 printf("The Maximum Number Is %d\n ",max);
 printf("The Minimum Number Is %d ",min);

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> The Maximum Number Is 40
>
> The Minimum Number Is 10